# Select "group" of rows with same column values(1 or more)

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have this table:

```
id      | column1 | column2
--------+---------+----------
1       | 3       | 1
2       | 5       | 1
3       | 6       | 2
4       | 5       | 2
5       | 1       | 3
6       | 7       | 3
7       | 7       | 3
8       | 2       | 3
9       | 5       | 3
10      | 7       | 4
```

(column2 is ordered for convenience, the rows are not in this order in the actual table)

How can I select a "group" of rows with the same value in column 2? It shouldn't necessarily return more than 1. Random would be fine but I would also prefer if I could sort it by some other column too.

If I am not making myself clear, this is what I want it to return:

```
id      | column1 | column2
--------+---------+----------
1       | 3       | 1
2       | 5       | 1
```

or

```
id      | column1 | column2
--------+---------+----------
3       | 6       | 2
4       | 5       | 2
```

or

```
id      | column1 | column2
--------+---------+----------
10      | 7       | 4
```

or... (etc)

So first it should return all the rows with the value 1 in column 2, then if I delete them it should return all the rows with the value 2 in column 2, etc.

Note that column2 is integer for the sake of simplicity and also I don't want to provide a specific value and column2 can have any value. The only way I can think of to make this work is with two queries:

First `SELECT column2 FROM test_table GROUP BY column2`, to get all the distinct column2 values and the do `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE column2=value` for each column2 value.

Is there a more efficient/short/single query way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using a subquery with `min`:

```
select t.*
from test_table t join (
    select min(column2) column2
    from test_table
    ) t2 on t.column2 = t2.column2
```

Comment: This works great but unfortunately in the actual table, column2 is not a number. I should have probably mentioned that and the fact that I wanted to sort by a different column(which isn't a number too) but I wanted to simplify the example and didn't think it would matter. Sorry, I will edit the question. Can I slightly change the min with an order by somehow?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that I can replace min(column2) with min(any-column-i-want). Thank you for your time, I will accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable
where column2 = (select column2 from yourtable
                 order by column2 limit 1)
```

find the smallest number in column2 and find records with this number